# I get no errors when adding a row to a DataTable, but the row is not added to the database

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, dataset, dataadapter

I am trying to add a row to a table in a PostgreSQL database using ODBC.  Although no exceptions are thrown, the row is not being added to the table.  Here is my code:

```
    void TestNewRow()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand =
                new OdbcCommand("select read_time from plant_genie.plc_values_by_tag", m_db.GetConnection());
            OdbcCommandBuilder builder =
                new OdbcCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.Fill(dataSet);

            DataTable valuesTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
            DataRow newRow = valuesTable.NewRow();
            newRow["read_time"] = DateTime.Now;
            valuesTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
            valuesTable.AcceptChanges();
            dataSet.AcceptChanges();
            adapter.Update(dataSet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            int a = 1;
        }
    }
```

I have a breakpoint in the exception handler and another at the end of the function.  The second breakpoint is hit but not the first, so no exception is being thrown.  I have triple-checked that I'm connecting to the correct database.  I don't think I should need two AcceptChanges() calls and an Update() call, but even with all of that overkill, I'm still not getting a new row in my table.  What am I doing wrong?

I tried to find a duplicate of this question, but there are so many questions about adding rows that if there was a duplicate, it is being hidden.

Thank you for your help.

RobR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `AcceptChanges` marks all changes as accepted (i.e. it resets the state of everything to `Unmodified`), so no changes will be saved to the database. Remove this call to both the table and dataset and your changes should be saved.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!  While I get far enough to mark your response as an answer, I'm still having trouble I'd appreciate help with.  Now I get an exception from PostgreSQL.  The PostgeSQL log contains this:

2014-03-03 11:39:35 EST ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "bokaro_five_charges.plant_genie.plc_values_by_tag" at character 13
2014-03-03 11:39:35 EST STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO Bokaro_five_charges.plant_genie.plc_values_by_tag (read_time) VALUES ('2014-03-03 11:39:35.483'::timestamp)

The database name is correct.  Is there a way to keep it out of the insert query?

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON: You can write your own insert, update, and delete commands on the `OdbcDataAdapter`. What you're getting now are automatically generated. The relevant properties are `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand`, and `DeleteCommand`. Just get rid of the `OdbcCommandBuilder`, then create your own commands and populate those properties (or whichever ones are appropriate). On each, you will need to create a parameter object and specify the column in your data that it should look at to get its value.